# Using PHP's APC (Alternative PHP Cache)?

Tags: linux, php, php-apc

I've installed APC.so successfully on my system, but I'm not sure what to do next...

PHP info says:

```
apc
APC Support     enabled
Version     3.0.19
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  no value
Locking type    pthread mutex Locks
Revision    $Revision: 3.154.2.5 $
Build Date  Sep 24 2010 05:10:07
```

How do I enable my application to use APC?

Comment: Does it not begin to accelerate the PHP files from the first time each is run?

Comment: Is that it? Don't I need to do anything special? How do I know that's its working?

Answer (score 3):

If APC is installed correctly, it will be used automatically by all scripts. You should see a speed improvement (usually in the form that your server can sustain more simultaneous page loads).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most basic things, you can cache variables by using:

```
apc_add('foo', $bar);
```

And retrieve them with:

```
apc_fetch('foo');
```

You can read more about how to use APC here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php